# Is there any way I can append the string the way I have described below?

Tags: java

I have string looks like this

```
 123_NAME

 MONTHLY
 MONTHLY 53_January_2013
 MONTHLY 54_February_2013
 MONTHLY 55_March_2013
 MONTHLY 56_April_2013

 QUARTERLY
 QUARTERLY 51_First_Quarter_2013
 QUARTERLY 54_Second_Quarter_2013
 QUARTERLY 57_Third_Quarter_2013
 QUARTERLY 60_Fourth_Quarter_2013
```

Above is the List of files I am pulling from Directory and printing as a list.The files are located in local machine in the same directory structure as above. For Example Folder Monthly wil contain files with names jan,feb,mar etc and folder quarterly contains files with name 1quarte,2nd quarter etc.

I need to append the list of files which I am printing like this

```
Monthly

Jan 2013
Feb 2013
Continue....

Quarterly

first Quarter 2013
second quarter 2013
Continue...
```

Below is part of my code will give some Idea

```
     Iterator<String> iterator=listFilesForFolder(folder, startWithDirectory, filesArray).iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String listofFiles=iterator.next();
        StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder(listofFiles);
        String test=str.substring(str.indexOf("/")+1);
        System.out.println(test);
```

Comment: As it's asked, the answer to your question is "Yes". You'll need to be more specific if you want a more specific answer! What's going wrong in the code you posted?

Comment: If they're all labeled like that, it'll be simpler to just do String parsing and splitting. For monthly, split on '_', first 3 chars of [1], and all of [2]. For Quarterly, same split, all of [1], [2], and [3].

Comment: When you look at my code System.out.println(a) prints the list of files which is string as you can see above at the very top, I need to figure out a way to append that string and make it look like Monthly>jan 2013,Feb2013  Quarterly> 1st quarter,2nd quarter as shown above. Thank You

Comment: Splitting looks like a good suggestion, I would also like to delete the name i.e 123_name on the very top. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `while` loop, you could try something like this if you don't mind hard-interpretation.

```
String[] split = listOfFiles.split("_")
if(split.length > 1) {
    if(split[0].contains("MONTHLY")) { //unique case
        System.out.println(split[1].substring(0, 3) + " " + split[2]);
    }
    else {
        for(int i = 1; i < split.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(split[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("\n" + listOfFiles + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think splitting would be the best way to go in this situation.Thank You Compass and Gurusharan.

Comment: @Lokesh my solution also eats the 123_name at the top. If the split is > 1 but there is no "MONTHLY" or "QUARTERLY" it will ignore it. If you have yearly or other options, you can add your own else statements.

Comment: Do you think I Can do the same with test instead of doing this for listofFiles? Since my original string looks differently and I have done some sub string in order to get the way we see now.

Comment: I ran into issue,There can be many title other than monthly and quarterly. Since it will be dynamic we cannot just search by string .contains("Monthly") or .contains(."Quarterly"). We cannot use .contains and hard code for thousands records.Is there any dynamic way to do this? Thank You

Comment: @Lokesh, I've updated my answer. It will handle the monthly uniquely, but for anything else, i.e. MONTHLY or YEARLY 51_2013, it will print everything after the first underscore. As long as the underscore prior is always there, it'll parse out the end of it.

Comment: By doing this , Getting faulty href link pointing to the folders inside monthly by default. For example Under Quarterly or Yearly it's pointing to the report file which is inside month. I have updated my code above.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want output in the following way (in the same line):

```
Folder > file1, file2, ...
```

instead of (in new lines):

```
Folder
File1
File2
```

If that's the case, did you know you have `System.out.print()` that does not print a new line at the end?

Try tweaking it, to insert the required separators (like commas and angular bracket).

Also since you ARE using StringBuilder, it has an `append()` method that you can use. However, I see no reason for using StringBuilder for `str` instead of using it for `test`.

Comment: No, At the very top box is What I am printing and the 2nd snippet box is how I want it to be where some kind of string splitting is required